# ERROR: UndefVarError: `setup` not defined when loading setup function in flux

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am using M1 mac (if that helps) and when I tried loading the `setup` function flux.jl and got the following error. `UndefVarError` setup `not defined`

The flux version I am using is 0.13.4. I created a new env to update it to the latest 0.13.17 and I still ended up with the same error.

Any idea how to fix this

```
using Flux: setup

ERROR: UndefVarError: `setup` not defined
Stacktrace:
  [1] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:370 [inlined]
  [2] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1864
  [3] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any}; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Base ./essentials.jl:816
  [4] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ Base ./essentials.jl:813
  [5] inlineeval(m::Module, code::String, code_line::Int64, code_column::Int64, file::String; softscope::Bool)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl:233
  [6] (::VSCodeServer.var"#66#70"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl:157
  [7] withpath(f::VSCodeServer.var"#66#70"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams}, path::String)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/repl.jl:249
  [8] (::VSCodeServer.var"#65#69"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl:155
  [9] hideprompt(f::VSCodeServer.var"#65#69"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/repl.jl:38
 [10] (::VSCodeServer.var"#64#68"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl:126
 [11] with_logstate(f::Function, logstate::Any)
    @ Base.CoreLogging ./logging.jl:514
 [12] with_logger
    @ ./logging.jl:626 [inlined]
 [13] (::VSCodeServer.var"#63#67"{VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl:225
 [14] #invokelatest#2
    @ ./essentials.jl:816 [inlined]
 [15] invokelatest(::Any)
    @ Base ./essentials.jl:813
 [16] macro expansion
    @ ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.47.2/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl:34 [inlined]
 [17] (::VSCodeServer.var"#61#62")()
    @ VSCodeServer ./task.jl:514
```

Comment: Somehow you are still using an old version of Flux. Perhaps by changing the env after loading Flux, which won't alter already-loaded code?

Comment: I'm using an M1 Mac, and `using Flux: setup` works just fine for me

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639110/julia-how-to-update-to-the-latest-version-of-a-package-i-e-flux

Comment: I installed Julia 1.92 and its all good now